# expected convolution2d_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150, 150, 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I trained my CNN, with gray scale images of size 150x150, and the training went without having any errors, however, whenever I try to run the model.predict() function I get this error :

`expected convolution2d_input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150, 150, 1)`

even though I do the exact same preprocessing for the images I pass to the predict function as the images I used to train the CNN. and they have a size of 150x150x1 just like my input shape in the CNN and just like the shape of the images I used to train the CNN with.

here is my CNN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(150, 150, 1), activation = 
'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax'))
```

The input is of size 150x150x1, and the expected input my CNN says it needs is (None, 150, 150, 1)

I have been trying to solve this issue for days now yet no luck whatsoever.

Comment: If you used batch while training wouldn;t your shape be, (Number of Example,150,150,1) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to make a prediction on a single image, you should add one dimension and then make the prediction like this:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(img)
```